# Activating virtual environment for python when "source bin/activate" not working?

Tags: python, virtualenv, command-prompt

I am trying to activate my virtual environment for Python but upon following many suggestions such as '''source bin/activate''', it comes up with ''''source' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.''' in the command prompt. How can I fix this? Or are there any other ways of activating my virtual env for python.

The virtual env in located on my desktop. I am trying to fix the "flask module not found".

Answer (score 0):

On windows use the batch file:

```
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

e.g.:

```
C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments